# The term 'select-object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

I am getting an error when starting SharePoint Management Shell for SP2013 on Windows Server 2012.

> select : The term 'Select-Object' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet,   function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or   if a path was included, verify that the
>   path is correct and try again.   At C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\SharePoint.ps1:1 char:16
>
> - $ver = $host | select version
> - ~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Select-Object:String) [], Comma
>       ndNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

do I need to import any modules ? If so, from where ?

Comment: Where is your code? Select-Object generally receives from piped inputs, *Get-Awesomeness | Select-Object AwesomePerson, TheirAddress*

Comment: @AthomSfere how does that problem relate to this?  It's clearly stating that Select-Object isn't recognized as a commandlet.  Take $null or an object without a version property and pipe it to Select .. you won't have this problem.

Comment: @ChrisN Select is an alias for Select-Object, like gci is an alias for Get-ChildItem. It is almost certainly a syntax error, but need some code to see whats going on.

Comment: They alias is setup, but the select-object command isn't loaded.  Simply read the error.  It's in English.

Comment: @PradeepNulu Can you simply open a regular powershell window and then import the sharepoint cmdlets like so: `Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"`

Comment: @ChrisN The problem is with select-object command as I am not able to run simple code with this in regular powershell window. The following code `get-process | select-object ProcessName` is also giving the same error "The term 'select-object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...".

Comment: How do I load  select-object command ?

Comment: Sorry Pradeep - if this is happening in every PowerShell window you open, I'm just not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks Chris for such a speedy response.

Comment: I also noticed that commands like `Format-List` are also not being recognized in regular powershell window. What is the module in which select, format-list cmdlets are defined ? How can load these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got work around for my problem.

Mine is an SharePoint 2013 box. I found $env:psmodulepath as `C:\Users\user_name\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;;C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\PowershellModules;C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\PowershellModules`
As you can notice that AppFabric module path has repeated itself. I guess AppFabric has messed up with the psmodulepath while it got installed.
So, I modified the `PSModulePath` variable under registry (at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`) to include `;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`
After this change, I am able to execute select & other basic cmdlets.

Thanks,
Pradeep Nulu